# Log4j2 - log4j2.xml configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am starting log4j2 new. I have a qquestion,

I have a log4j2 xml file and i want to save logs in own level.
Forexample info level logs save in info.txt file, error level logs save in error.txt file.
This is mine log4j2.xml codes;

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>

    <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>


    <RollingFile name="trace-log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        fileName="${log-path}/trace.log" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="info-log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        fileName="${log-path}/info.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="error-log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        fileName="${log-path}/error.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.test.log4j2" level="debug">
        <appender-ref level="debug" ref="trace-log" />
        <appender-ref level="error" ref="error-log" />
        <appender-ref level="debug" ref="console-log" />
        <appender-ref level="info" ref="info-log" />
    </Logger>
    <Root additivity="false" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="error-log" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: is it working or not? If not what's the issue?

Comment: It is only saving error.log file. info log is not saving.

Comment: that's because you defined it in root logger.

Comment: so? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using Filter.

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>

    <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>


    <RollingFile name="trace-log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        fileName="${log-path}/trace.log" >

        <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>

        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="info-log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        fileName="${log-path}/info.log">

        <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>

        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="error-log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        fileName="${log-path}/error.log">

        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
  <AppenderRef level="DEBUG" ref="trace-log" />
  <AppenderRef level="ERROR" ref="error-log" />
  <AppenderRef level="DEBUG" ref="console-log" />
  <AppenderRef level="INFO" ref="info-log" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly you don't understand how the threshold filter works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define separate loggers for this.

Try something like:

```
<Loggers>
   <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef level="DEBUG" ref="trace-log" />
      <AppenderRef level="ERROR" ref="error-log" />
      <AppenderRef level="DEBUG" ref="console-log" />
      <AppenderRef level="INFO" ref="info-log" />
   </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: I tired but all off log files log same. I want only, error logs in error.log file, info logs in info.log file.
But in yours code three files have got same log values.

Comment: When i wrote "logger.trace()", it should be save in trace.log file.
When i wrote "logger.info()", it should be save in info.log file.
When i wrote "logger.error()", it should be save in error.log file.

But in here trace.log file, info.log file and error.log file have error level message. All files log value same.

Comment: Am not sure what's your config is, but even it says the same [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level)